# POST request to `/users` for an existing user causes activation email to be re-sent

Tags: docusignapi

I am looking for a way to re-send the activation email for users. I noticed that making a POST request to `/users` for an existing user does precisely this (and in addition, if the user has userState='Active', it gets changed to 'ActivationSent').

For instance, making a POST request with the following data twice, will result in two activation emails being sent to joe@email.com:

```
{'newUsers': [{'email': 'joe@email.com',
               'userName': 'joe@email.com',
               'firstName': 'Joe',
               'lastName': 'Smith'}]}
```

I would like to confirm that this is indeed the correct behavior which I can rely upon, as I did not find this described in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is, in fact, adding the same user again. When a user is added, an activation email is sent and the status is ActivationSent.
So while this is accomplishing what you wanted, technically, it's still just adding a user and emailing them to activate but you are correct that it's a way to "resend" the activation email to a user.

Comment: I'm also seeing the `USER_ALREADY_EXISTS_IN_ACCOUNT, message=Username and email combination already exists for this account.` error.  So far not able to figure out when I get this vs the activation email getting re-sent.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: hmmm, I wonder if you're using a different name combination when it does the activation? since the email is unique to activation, but the name has to match. Try to have the UserName be different but email the same and see